# Jssor Slideshow where images are referenced in a loop

Tags: jssor

I'm using ExpressionEngine to dynamically reference images within the body of my html display page. Essentially this is the same as creating a foreach loop in php that dynamically creates the gallery and thumbnails. In ExpressionEngine this is done like this:

```
{photos}
<div> <img u="image" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/img/01.jpg" /> <img u="thumb" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/img/thumb-01.jpg" /> </div>
{/photos}
```

Where {photos} is equivalent to foreach in php, I've also just used the same image for simplicity.

When the page loads the slider doesn't fully work. The images and thumbnails display, you can click a thumbnail to show that image, etc. What doesn't work is the navigation arrows. They are dysfunctional and the left arrow doesn't even display.
[image]
As the attached screenshot shows, this three image slideshow is missing the left navigation arrow and the right navigation arrow does not function.

Is there a work around that I can implement? I've see some other posts that talk about dynamic loading of images, but it doesn't seem they are the same issue as mine.

Help would be grateful as I think Jssor is better than anything I've used in the past.

Comment: It's correct, you've got it worked already. As there are only 3 images, the thumbnail navigator can't loop. The problem is that the right arrow should not show. And it has been already fixed. Please download the latest version again.

Comment: Great works fine now